# JSP delete file after download it

Tags: java, jsp

using following code for download file

```
<%@page import="java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException"%>
<%@page import="java.nio.channels.FileLock"%>
<%@page import="java.nio.channels.FileChannel"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat"%>
<%@page contentType="application/octet-stream"%>
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page language="java" import="java.io.*,java.net.*,java.util.*,javax.servlet.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%

        BufferedInputStream filein = null;
        BufferedOutputStream output = null;
        try {

            File file = new File("d:/ttt.mp3"); // path of file
            if (file.exists()) {


                byte b[] = new byte[2];        
                int len = 0;
                filein = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
                output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
                response.setContentType("application/force-download");
                response.setHeader("content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Backup.gz");
                response.setHeader("content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
                while ((len = filein.read(b)) > 0) {
                    output.write(b, 0, len);

                    output.flush();

                 //   output.close();

                }


                Calendar present = Calendar.getInstance();
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                String a = sdf.format(present.getTime());
                String ip = request.getRemoteAddr();
                String mail = session.getAttribute("emailid").toString();
                try {
                    PreparedStatement pst = null;
                    String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/logapp_log";
                    Connection connection = null;
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                    connection = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "nic@123");
                    String query = "insert into logapp_log_table(uname,date_time,user_ip) values ('" + mail + "','" + a + "','" + ip + "')";
                    pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                    pst.executeUpdate();
                    pst.close();
                    connection.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            } else {
                session.setAttribute("Ferror", "File not available Or Deleted");
                getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/link.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.print(ex.getMessage());
        }

    %>
</body>
```

this code is work fine ... 
and below code for delete that file after download ...

```
File file = new File("d:/ttt.mp3");
       if(file.exists()) { 

        if (file.delete()) {

            System.out.println("File Deleted");
            session.setAttribute("Ferror","Deleted");
            getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/link.jsp").forward(request, response);
            response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Delete failed");
            session.setAttribute("Ferror","Under Process");
            getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/link.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
       }
       else {


           session.setAttribute("Ferror","File not available Or Deleted");
           getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/link.jsp").forward(request, response);
       }
```

delete code is work fine , when i delete file other then i download 
i need when user download a file he can also delete that file after download it , but my download code is not working .. it print the else code which is delete failed

please give me the way to delete that file .. or any other way to immediately  delete the file after download is complete .

Comment: possible reason is that file is in use

Comment: yes that is the reason .. through this i am not able to delete that file manually

Comment: give me the way to delete that file forcefully

Comment: @vegeta  .. I think you should be bit polite when asking for such direct help.

Comment: I don't think that @vegeta is intending to be impolite at all, but it does appear that English is not his first language; give him a break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You opened file for reading and forgot to close it. Since you are on Windows that locks open files you cannot then delete it. Call `filein.close()` in finally block after sending file to client. Then try to remove it. I hope this will work.

On linux it can't happen! :)

Comment: it's working fine .. when i download file from browsers's downloader .. But if i download from Internet Download manager or other third party downloader . it's give me the same problem...

Answer (score 2):

As @AlexR said, you should close the file before deleting it under windows.

```
try{
    filein = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    //do your work
}finally{
    if(filein!=null){
        filein.close(); //close the file
    }
}
```

Closing file inputstream to release file handler under Unix like OS.

Comment: it's working fine .. when i download file from browsers's downloader .. But if i download from Internet Download manager or other third party downloader . it's give me the same problem...

Comment: Internet Download manager or other third party downloader will use multi-threading downloading. So you need a lock to avoid multi-downloading or watching the counter of downloading and delete the file while the counter is zero.